# Sprockets and rails 3 - adding a new precompiled js file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sprockets

I currently have a file `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` which has a list of requires in it, and which, when i run `rake assets:precompile` cleans, minifies and concatenates all of the listed files into `public/assets/application.js`.  That's all working fine.

However, i want to add another precompiled js file called 'show_tale.js', with a different list of js files to pull in.  I've added a `show_tale.js` file into `app/assets/javascripts` which has the list of requires in it.  But, when i do `rake assets:precompile`, it doesn't build a `public/assets/show_tale.js` file like i want it to.

I'm guessing that in some config file i need to add 'show_tales' or 'show_tales.js' into some list or option, but i can't work out where/how to do this.  Can anyone set me straight?

thanks, max

Answer (score 3):

Found it, it was pretty obvious really.  It's been a long week :)  In `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( show_tale.js )
```

Comment: Moved to config/initializers/assets.rb in Rails 4.