# how to precompile page specific assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I used the following code to include custom css and javscript on a specific page of my rails app.

```
<% content_for :header do -%>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'mycustompagecssfile' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'customjavascriptfile' %>
<% end -%>
```

It works on localhost (provided I included the yield `<%= yield(:header) if content_for(:header) %>` in the application layout) but when I push it to Heroku it breaks the app.

Because those css and javascript files are included only on the one page, I am not including them in the manifest file (because I don't want those styles to appear everywhere), in fact, i removed `require tree` code

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require common
//= require live-comment-preview
//= require_self
```

so I'm wondering if I precompile the assets (which I'm required to do for heroku) then these page specific css and javascript files are not being precompiled, and that's causing the heroku app to break (I'm guessing)

the heroku logs say there's an internal server error

```
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2013-01-07T17:13:58+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 25ms
```

Note, I'm quite certain that it's the assets (rather than the ruby code) that's causing the problem, as if I do just this (i.e. remove the assets) in the page there's no problem

```
<% content_for :header do -%>

 <% end -%>
```

Can anyone tell me how to precompile those page specific assets?

Comment: Try this: `<%= yield(:header) if content_for?(:header) %>`

Comment: adding a question mark after content_for (content_for?) doesn't fix the problem...

Comment: Have you added your custom CSS and files to the list of files to be precompiled? See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272325/sprockets-and-rails-3-adding-a-new-precompiled-js-file

Answer (score 2):

I had to precompile the page-specific assets in config/environments/production.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += [ "pagespecific.js", "pagespecific.css"]
```